# If/Elseif statement kept going wrong when I add it into a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I tried this one but the if/elseif statement kept having problem. Im not sure what's wrong with this... Thanks for any help!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    For i = 3 To 13 Step 3
        For j = 2 To 4
            Set curcell = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, j)
            If curcell.Value < 0.1 Then curcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            ElseIf curcell.Value >= 0.1 And curcell.Value < 0.3 Then curcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: As is your code will not compile since you used a one-liner self terminating *IF Statement*. In short, you will have a compile error on the *ElseIf* line. You need to construct your if correctly. I'll post it as answer so you'll see the difference but it is the same code you have.

Comment: `If condition Then` on one line.  `ElseIf condition Then` on one line.  `End If` on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, this is how you write your *If clause*:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long, curcell As Range

    For i = 3 To 13 Step 3
        For j = 2 To 4
            Set curcell = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, j)
            If curcell.Value < 0.1 Then
                curcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            ElseIf curcell.Value >= 0.1 And curcell.Value < 0.3 Then
                curcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Take note of the difference:

```
If curcell.Value < 0.1 Then curcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

Above line is a self terminating one-liner *If Statement*.
So below line:

```
ElseIf curcell.Value >= 0.1 And curcell.Value < 0.3 Then curcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 7
```

will produce a *Compile Error* since it's like a floating *ElseIf* without *If*.
So if the next *End If* since no existing *If* needs to be terminated or ended since you used a one-liner *If* in the first condition.
I don't know if this does what you want but I just corrected the *If construct*.
HTH.

Comment: You've declared `curcell` as a variant. You need to specify `As range`.

Comment: @JonCrowell Yep, that should be the case. In OP's original code, it was not declared, I just did cause as is, it returns *variable declaration* error at my end. Failed to explicitly declare it as range :) Thanks for noticing. Fixed it now.

Comment: I only noticed because I did the same thing in my answer. (deleted because you had just answered the same thing!) Thanks for fixing -- upvote now registered.

Comment: @JonCrowell Yeah noticed too. If you're a minute or 2 earlier, I would've deleted mine :D